Kernel not outputting anything
I am trying to write a simple os, and I'm just getting started but I keep getting it wrong and I'm not sure how.
Here is my code:
kernel.c
// kernel.c

#define VIDEO_MEMORY 0xB8000

void write_string(const char* str); // Function declaration

void kernel_main() {
    // Write some text to the screen
    const char* message = "Hello, world!";
    write_string(message);

    // Enter an infinite loop
    while (1);
}

void write_string(const char* str) {
    // Write string to video memory (text mode)
    volatile char* video_memory = (volatile char*) VIDEO_MEMORY;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        video_memory[i * 2] = str[i];      // Character
        video_memory[i * 2 + 1] = 0x0F;    // Attribute (white on black)
    }
}

; bootloader.asm

; Define the entry point
    BITS 16
    ORG 0x7C00

; Main bootloader code
start:
    ; Disable interrupts
    cli

    ; Output debug message
    mov si, debug_msg
    call print_string

    ; Load kernel from disk
    mov ax, 0x0201    ; AH=2 (read sectors), AL=1 (number of sectors to read)
    mov bx, 0x8000    ; ES:BX = 0x8000:0x0000 (destination address)
    mov cx, 0x0002    ; Cylinder 0, Sector 2
    mov dh, 0x00      ; Head 0
    mov dl, 0x80      ; Drive 0x80 (first floppy drive)
    int 0x13          ; BIOS interrupt for disk I/O

    ; Check for error
    jc disk_error

    ; Jump to kernel entry point
    jmp 0x8000:0x0000

; Error handling code
disk_error:
    ; Display error message and halt
    mov si, error_msg
    call print_string
    cli
    hlt

; Print string subroutine
print_string:
    lodsb            ; Load next byte from SI into AL
    cmp al, 0        ; Check for null terminator
    je print_done    ; If null terminator, return
    mov ah, 0x0E     ; BIOS teletype function
    int 0x10         ; Call BIOS interrupt
    jmp print_string ; Repeat for next character
print_done:
    ret

; Data section
error_msg db "Error loading kernel!", 0
debug_msg db "Booting kernel...", 0

; Padding and boot signature
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

compile.sh
nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o bootloader.bin
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 --oformat binary kernel.o
dd if=bootloader.bin of=disk.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=2 conv=notrunc

I only get Booting kernel...
when ideally I would get that in addition to Hello, world!
I run it with: qemu-system-i386 -hda disk.img
I have tried looking online, and asking chat-gpt but I can't seem to find an answer.
All help appreciated.
Thanks.

Where is your stack?

GCC is going to build 32-bit or 64-bit code (you can select which using -m32 or -m64).  So you have to switch to the appropriate mode before you can jump into GCC-compiled code.  This takes some work as you have to set up various data structures for the CPU (descriptor tables for 32-bit protected mode, page tables for 64-bit long mode).  https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page is a good resource.

You also have to do some other initialization to set up the environment that C code expects: allocate stack space and point the stack pointer there, and zero the .bss section.  If your kernel binary isn't linked for the fixed address where you load it, then you also have to fixup all the internal memory references.

And -Ttext 0x1000 seems wrong if you are intending to load your kernel at linear address 0x80000.

As your comment says, you need to pass int 0x13 / ah = 0x02 a far pointer in es:bx.  You say you want that to be 0x8000:0x0000, but you have loaded bx with 0x8000 instead of 0x0000, and you haven't initialized es at all.  By the way, you also need to initialize the other segment registers with 0 to match your org 0x7c00; BIOSes sometimes happen to leave them zeroed but it's not guaranteed.

You might consider using Bochs instead of QEMU at first; its debugger is better for 16-bit code.  You really do need to be able to use a debugger to single-step your code; that's how you get out of this cycle of "wrote some code and ran it, doesn't work, don't know why not", short of having to post to Stack Overflow every five minutes.

The world of qemu has only a few specialists. Best to use tags to draw them in to comment orr help on your Q. (I am not such a specialist (-; ) . Good Luck!
